# WSDL mode causing segmentation faults

Tags: wsdl, wso2, wso2-esb

I have Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, which uses PHP 5.3.2. I'm trying to get WSO2 for PHP 2.1.0 working, and am confidant I've installed all the requisite packages. The compile and install was successful, and I've gone back over the installation instructions several times to confirm I've not missed any steps.

Nearly all the samples scripts provided work perfectly.

Two of the samples however (WSDL mode Client using WSDL 1.1, and WSDL mode Client using WSDL 2.0) are producing segmentation faults.  As soon as either of these two samples are run, this appears in my Apache2 error log:

```
[Tue Jun 12 07:44:18 2012] [notice] child pid 18246 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

It seems WSDL mode is somehow broken.

I have the following directives in my `php.ini`:

```
extension = "wsf.so"
wsf.home = "/usr/lib/php5/20090626/wsf_c"
wsf.log_path = "/var/log"
wsf.log_level = 4
```

Can anyone provide some insight as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64-bit) on a virtual machine, and configured WSO2 for PHP 2.1.0 on it.  Everything compiled perfectly, but I'm still getting segmentation faults on the WSDL samples.

Comment: Another follow up...  I installed a WAMP stack on my Windows 7 PC, and went through the installation of the WSO2 for PHP 2.1.0 Windows binary.  The WSDL sample work just fine.  Is there a Linux incompatibility here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check which version of SSL you're using on the WAMP compared to Ubutnu.
I've found this issue which might be a clue:
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/WSFPHP-467